# Why are my Jinja tracebacks meaningless?

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

I don't know why, but lately the tracebacks I get from Jinja template rendering
errors are more or less completely meaningless.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/my_project/app/distlib/tipfy/__init__.py", line 442, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(request, e)
  File "/Users/me/my_project/app/distlib/tipfy/__init__.py", line 430, in wsgi_app
    rv = self.dispatch(request)
  File "/Users/me/my_project/app/distlib/tipfy/__init__.py", line 559, in dispatch
    return handler(self, request)(method, **request.rule_args)
  File "/Users/me/my_project/app/distlib/tipfy/__init__.py", line 165, in __call__
    response = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/my_project/app/my_package/admin/menus/editor.py", line 22, in get
    return self.edit_week(menu, year, week_num, week_nums)
  File "/Users/me/my_project/app/my_package/admin/menus/editor.py", line 44, in edit_week
    return self.respond(data, context=ctx, template="admin/menus/edit.html")
  File "/Users/me/my_project/app/my_package/lib/irender.py", line 182, in respond
    return render(self, fmt, opts)
  File "/Users/me/my_project/app/my_package/lib/irender.py", line 207, in __call__
    val = render_func(handler, **opts)
  File "/Users/me/my_project/app/my_package/lib/irender.py", line 220, in render_html
    return handler.render_template(self.template, ctx)
  File "/Users/me/my_project/app/my_package/handlers.py", line 42, in render_template
    return jinja2.get_template(template).render(accum)
  File "/Users/me/my_project/app/distlib/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/Users/me/my_project/app/templates/admin/menus/edit.html", line 3, in top-level template code
    {% import "admin/utils.html" as utils %}
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Of course I can deduce where the actual error is by removing most of the
template and seeing when the bug starts occuring, but that's a dumb development
method.

How do I make the tracebacks useful again?

By the way, I have the following incantation in my main.py:

```
def whitelist_jinja2_debug_modules():
    from google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver import HardenedModulesHook
    HardenedModulesHook._WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES += ['_ctypes', 'gestalt']

if app.dev:
    whitelist_jinja2_debug_modules()
```

Comment: Turns out the problem was in a template that was imported via `{% import ... %}`, the erroneous line was `{% for base in range(52 / 13) %}` -- the question still remains though.

Comment: Put your calculations in python code instead of a template?

Comment: Seems like a myopic approach to user interface design.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debug Jinja2 in Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086091/debug-jinja2-in-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is quite old already, the answer is readily available (and not at the same time). To get proper stacktraces in Jinja you need to have ctypes which wasn't available in the Google app engine for a long time. I'm not entirely sure about the current status but this question has some solutions for you:
[Debug Jinja2 in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086091/debug-jinja2-in-google-app-engine)