# Using app engine interactive console with jinja2 template

Tags: debugging, google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

```
from jinja2 import Template
template = Template('Hello {{ name }}!')
template.render(name='John Doe')
```

I have entered the above into app engine's interactive console and get no output. How can I get output?

I have tried adding the code I found at the following link to the console, but still no output.

[Debug Jinja2 in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086091/debug-jinja2-in-google-app-engine)

Thanks,

Brian in Atlanta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add a print. Try this:

```
from jinja2 import Template
template = Template('Hello {{ name }}!')
print template.render(name='John Doe')
```

Comment: Perfect. I had tried on the next line "print template" put got info I could not use. Thanks, very much.