# Google AppEngine - enabling ctypes - cannot import simplejson from dev_appserver

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, ctypes, simplejson

I am trying to use _ctypes with the Google AppEngine Development Server, according to this answer:

[Debug Jinja2 in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086091/debug-jinja2-in-google-app-engine/3694434)

Here is the code I use:

```
import os
if os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Dev'):
    # Enable ctypes for Jinja debugging
    from google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver import HardenedModulesHook
    HardenedModulesHook._WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES += ['_ctypes', 'gestalt']
```

But I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named simplejson
```

It comes from line 4: `from google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver import HardenedModulesHook`

I tried:

```
sudo pip install simplejson
```

The install succeeded, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those instructions are tied to the old dev appserver.
The new dev appserver has a very different structure, which may be breaking that hack.

Try running using the old dev appserver.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/old_devserver